# Force Activity to redraw the full layout on Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, orientation

I would like to force my `Activity` to redraw layout on orientation change. I don't want it to restart the `Activity` though. I know that I have to override `onConfigurationChanged` to get the callback for orientation change. One way that I know of doing it will be to call `setContentView` again with same layout. Is there any better way to force a redraw of Activity layout ?

Comment: force my Activity to redraw means you want to show different layout design?

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur No. I would like it to show the same layout. But I want it to be re-drawn. Because I am using some custom views from libraries. Those views implement onDraw to handle rotation changes. But when it is used from android app, rotation is not getting handled. So I will have to redraw the entire layout so that the view's onMeasure will be invoked

Comment: I guess you could try calling [`requestLayout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()) on the root view in the activity (i.e. your top-level container, or use `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`). As mentioned in the docs: *"To initiate a layout, call `requestLayout()`. This method is typically called by a `View` on itself when it believes that is can no longer fit within its current bounds."*

Answer (score 0):

Please add following line

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

in your AndroidMenifest in your activity tag.

It may work.